# How can i Display div Elements in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi everyone i want o display 3 elements in a row. I have tried the following code but it is not displaying them correctly.

```
    <div id="mainDiv" style="background-color:#f77f00; width:90%; margin-right:5%; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:1%; margin-top:1%;" >
        <div id="left" onclick="Deletefav(this)"  style="display: inline; width:20%; float:left; ">'+
            '<img style="display: inline;" src="" />
        </div>'+

        <div id="center" onclick=""  style=" width:30%;  display: inline;text-align: center; margin:10%;">
            <p style="display: inline;"><font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="4">testing</font></p>
        </div>

        <div id="right" onclick="Callfav(this)"  style="display: inline; width:20%; float:right;">
            <img style="display: inline;" src="" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is displaying like this

[image: Above code is displaying this, i don't know why text is according to images]

I want to create it like the sample image[image: Sample]

Comment: Your image looks like they're all in a row to me. What wrong with it?

Comment: Please read my question again i have made few changes, that can explain it better

Comment: Please post valid html that the community can work with to reproduce the problem. Or provide something like a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem. And try to avoid inline styles , which makes your code extremely difficult to work with… [Why Use Css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: @TJ is right i m agree with him

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give display property `inline-block` for inner divs:

```
  display:inline-block;
```

**Update:**

you need to set the height for div that has `jo will fix it` as other to div have images in them:

```html
<div
  id="${id}"
  style="
    background-color: #f77f00;
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
  "
>
  <div
    id="${_id}"
    onclick="Deletefav(this)"
    style="background-color: #f77f00; float: left; width: 20%; display: inline-block"
  >
    <img style="" src="${del_image}" /> <font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="1">delete</font>
  </div>

  <div
    id="${_id}"
    onclick=""
    style="background-color: #f77f00; float: left; width: 50%; display: inline-block; height: 25px"
  >
    <font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="4">${name}</font>
  </div>

  <div
    id="${_id}"
    onclick="Callfav(this)"
    style="background-color: #f77f00; float: left; width: 20%; display: inline-block"
  >
    <img style="" src="${call_image}" /><font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="1">call</font>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And adjust the width too. Right?

Comment: Please read my question again i have made few changes, that can explain it better

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the child divs.

Set the height of the child divs:

1. Possibility: Set the height for all the child divs: `height: 20px /* or in %, em, etc */;`
2. Possibility: Set the height for the child divs: `height: inherit;` which gives the height from the parent div to the children divs

From W3Schools:

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its parent element.
>
> The inherit keyword can be used for any CSS property, and on any HTML
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

To display all `<div>` elements in one row you can just try:

```
display:'flex'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix then you can use another element with `clear:both;` property:

```
'</div> <br style="clear:both; height:0;" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

add height to your second div which is not correctly displayed like

```
<div id="${_id}" onclick="" style="height=40px; background-color:#f77f00; float:left; width:50%;">
  <p style="">
    <font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="4">${name}</font>
  </p> 
</div>
```

Add like **style="height=40px; ..."**

Answer (score 0):

Here i have written some code that might solve this issue (:

```css
section > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#f77f00; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:10%;
}
section {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin:1%;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color:#f77f00; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div>
        <img style=" " src="http://i58.tinypic.com/16c9ulk.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p style=""><font color="#000" face="verdana" size="4">JO willl fix it </font>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img style="" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/b4ddtu.png" />
    </div>
</section>

<section style="background-color:#f77f00; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div>
        <img style=" " src="http://i58.tinypic.com/16c9ulk.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p style=""><font color="#fff" face="verdana" size="4">JO willl fix it </font>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img style="" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/b4ddtu.png" />
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 25% 5%;
  display: inline-flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .child {
  border: 0 solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0012;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <p>Much more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```