# Put three form buttons on a line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons that display in a vertical line and I want them to display horizontally

```
            <form method="twitch" action= "https://www.twitch.tv/">
              <button type="submit"><img src="img/twitch.png" alt="Twitch"></button>
            </form>
             <form method="Instagram" action="https://www.instagram.com/">
              <button type="submit"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" > </button>
            </form>
            <form method="linkedin" action="https://www.linkedin.com/">
              <button type="submit"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" ></button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i Display div Elements in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799877/how-can-i-display-div-elements-in-one-row)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in a parent `div` and, in your CSS, set that `div` to `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put each `form` and `button` inside individual `<div>`'s, wrap those `<div>`'s in a parent `<div>`, and then use `flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/hnkqsjba/2/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.first, .second, .third {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <form method="twitch" action= "https://www.twitch.tv/">
    <button type="submit"><img src="img/twitch.png" alt="Twitch">
    </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <form method="Instagram" action="https://www.instagram.com/">
    <button type="submit"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" ></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <form method="linkedin" action="https://www.linkedin.com/">
    <button type="submit"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" > </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In css add to each one of them `float: left;`

Comment: That would be a good solution... 10 years ago

Comment: What makes it not good? Is it slow?

Comment: float:left might work just fine but for that case, it's much better practice to use display:flex because it gives the same result and allows you to use a lot of more parent-related properties from CSS Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block;
most people use flex but its not good becasue some of the old browsers can't understand flex.!
but all of the browsers support inline block

Comment: False. https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex

Comment: Chrome and FireFox and IE old vers can't run it its totally true.!

Comment: Did You make sure that these browsers are even supported ? ;)

Comment: Dude your web should support every single browsers... :) 
that means you are a pro ui designer because everyone can use flex but its only you that can do something special :)

Comment: and of course even last version of IE is partial supported.
lots of users still use IE so... ?

Comment: Good luck than  sir !